# Height and margin not working with inflated and addview?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-inflate

Here's my `EditText`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="49dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
    android:text=""
    android:ems="10"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:imeOptions="actionNext"
    android:maxLines="1"
    android:background="@drawable/profile_edt_round_corners"
    android:drawablePadding="5dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:hint=""
    tools:ignore="RtlSymmetry"
    android:textColor="#4a4a4a"/>
```

Inflating the view

```
private fun getRoundedEditText() =
    layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.v_rounded_corners, null) as EditText
```

Setting the values

```
private fun addDataToParents() {
    val editTextView = getRoundedEditText()
    editTextView.setText("Parent 1")
    ll_parents_guardian_container.addView(editTextView)
    val editTextView2 = getRoundedEditText()
    editTextView2.setText("Parent 2")
    ll_parents_guardian_container.addView(editTextView2)
}
```

Where `ll_parents_guardian_container` is

```
<LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/ll_parents_guardian_container"
            android:orientation="vertical">
    </LinearLayout>
```

However the `layout_marginTop` and `layout_height` which i had already defined in XML is not reflected there.

Comment: what is the container root layout?

Comment: try to set the layoutparams progmatically and see

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out the issue.

```
layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.v_rounded_corners, null) as EditText
```

While inflating a view which has margin/ height properties, you shouldn't pass the root as null. This is the cause of the issue. Because the inflated view needs the root to draw the layout params.

So change it with the view on which you're going to add.

```
layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.v_rounded_corners, ll_parents_guardian_container ) as EditText
```

Comment: I encountered the same issue with 0 margins, but was inflating views using view binding: `ActivityMyExampleBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)`. 

It was necessary to use a different overload, `ActivityMyExampleBinding.inflate(layoutInflater, container, true)` (the last argument automatically calls `addView()` for you, if `false` you must do it yourself). 

It appears that the generated binding `.java` class is implicitly passing `null` as the parent `ViewGroup` when you use the first overload.

Comment: @WillWestrop can you do a debug by adding a breakpoint, that can easily find the root cause. if you still find it difficult please add a question and mention me.

Comment: I've got it working, thanks. Was just dropping a note in case people in future stumble upon this, that using view binding you can experience the same issue, but there, the passing of `null` for the container is hidden behind the binding class generated by the compiler (unless you know to use the correct method overload)